# MySQL Indexes - Join and Order By need different indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design

I am working on constructing a social feed, just like Twitter.

I have a table of `posts`, `users`, and `followers`.

My goal is to optimize the feed query that will fetch all posts of the users you are following and order them by recency.

The query looks like:

```
SELECT * from posts inner join followers on followers.user_id = posts.user_id
where followers.followed_by_id = {authenticatedUser.id}
order by posts.created_at DESC
```

However, I cannot get the indexes to work for both the `JOIN` and the `ORDER BY`. What is the ideal query and index setup to make this query scale?

We have hundreds of thousands of `users` and millions of `posts`.

Thanks in advance! <3 I appreciate all of you.

Comment: *We have hundreds of thousands of users and millions of posts* - maybe consider being a bit more selective than "all posts since the dawn of time by all users followed by user X" ? Perhaps relieve the db of the burden of sorting the data too

Comment: Having a simple index for the `followers (followed_by_id, user_id)` should help quite a bit.

Comment: @slaakso nothing for posts?

Comment: @CaiusJard was kind of assuming the `posts` had already an index for `user_id`. Kind of obvious choise. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: *cannot get the indexes to work for ... the ORDER BY* - I don't quite see how it would help, given that you're `select *`ing anyway, so any possibility of optimizing a query to "answered from the index without hitting the table" is lost, and the data that needs to drive the order is in the resultset. I recommend to think more carefully about the data you really need to retrieve

Comment: If it helps, I can `select activities.*`.

Comment: Huh?  Where did `activities` come from?

Comment: `select posts.*` my b.

Answer (score 0):

```
followers:  INDEX(followed_by_id, user_id)  -- composite; order is important
```

Don't say `SELECT *`, instead, spell out the columns actually needed.  This *may* lead to defining a "covering" index.

`INDEX(user_id, created_at)` will *not* help.  This is because multiple user_ids are involved.

Changing to `ORDER BY user_id, created_at` should allow that index to help.

If you have a `WHERE` or `LIMIT` that you did not show, that could change the analysis dramatically.